# using getline instead of cin >>

Tags: c++

Hey guys so my program is as follows, but when i input a word starting with w,d, b, or q like for example deposit instead of the letter d the program just keeps repeating the initial question of "would you like to withdraw , deposit etc." I tried to convert the cin>> to getline( cin, user_request) but that gave me an error. i am pretty sure the way to fix this is to convert the cin to getline but im not sure how to properly. if anyone can help out. and is there a way to do this program with the cin statements?  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char user_request;
   string user_string;
   double account_balance, dollars_withdraw, dollars_deposit;

   account_balance = 5000;
   user_request= user_string[0];


   while(account_balance =>0)
     {
        cout << "Would you like to Withdraw, Deposit, Check your balance or Quit?" 
           << endl;
        cin >> user_request;
        if (user_request == 'w' || user_request== 'W')
        {
           cout << "How much would you like to withdraw?" << endl;
           cin >> dollars_withdraw;
        if (dollars_withdraw > account_balance)
           cout << "Invalid transaction" << endl;
        else 
           account_balance = account_balance - dollars_withdraw;
           cout << "Your new balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
        }

        if (user_request == 'd' || user_request== 'D')
        {
           cout << "How much would you like to deposit?" << endl;
           cin >> dollars_deposit;
           account_balance= account_balance + dollars_deposit;
           cout << "Your new balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
        }
        if (user_request == 'b' || user_request == 'B')
      {
           account_balance= account_balance;
           cout << "Your available balance is $" << account_balance << endl;
      }
        if (user_request == 'q' || user_request == 'Q')
           break;
   }

   cout << "Goodbye" << endl;



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the error into your question so that we know what we're trying to fix.

Answer (score 4):

While `user_request` is a `char`, then each non-space character in the input will satisfy another `cin >> user_request;` statement, so entering "deposit" will loop through 7 times, with only the 'd' matching an `if` statement, but the prompt message being printed each time.

You should change `user_request` to be a `std::string`, then `getline(cin, user_request)` *will* work, but you'll need to compare `user_request`'s first character (i.e. `[0]`) to e.g. `"w"` (a string literal) instead of `'w'` (a character literal).

It's also considered good practice to check whether the input request worked - an end-of-file condition would cause your loop to "spin" forever.

It's also a good idea to change your prompt so it mentions the letters you'd like them to type, otherwise they'd probably type e.g. 'c' rather than 'b' for "check balance".  Just `cout` something like:

```
Would you like to [W]ithdraw, [D]eposit, Check your [b]alance or [Q]uit?
```

So, all up:

```
std::string user_request;

if (not getline(cin, user_request))    // or !getline(...) if your compiler lacks "not"
    break;

if (user_request.empty())
    continue;  // avoid [0] on an empty line, which may crash the program

if (user_request[0] == "w" || user_request[0] == "W")
    ...
```

Comment: he already is including std::string (user_string is of type std::string)

Comment: @Alan: he was doing `getline(cin,user_request)` which was a `char`. Though he didn't tell us what the error was, that use of `char` with `getline` was probably the error.

Comment: @Tony: no worries. @Ken: Right. However I was just pointing out that he doesn't need to include <string> as it was already included. The answer has been changed to reflect that information.

Comment: @Ken: Alan meant that my now edited-out advice that he #include <string> wasn't necessary because he was already including it and the user_string variable was a string.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yea the error message prints that it can not deduce argument from char

Answer (score 2):

Either take a `std::string` from standard in, which will input a word (delimited by whitespace)

```
std::string input;
if( std::cin >> input ) {
    if( ! input.empty() && input[0] == 'd' || input[0] == 'D' )
        // ...
}
```

or take an entire line with `std::getline()`:

```
std::string line;
if( std::getline(std::cin, line) ) {
    if( ! line.empty() && line[0] == 'd' || line[0] == 'D' )
        // ...
}
```

Of course, in the case of taking a `std::string` from `std::cin` if the user enters multiple words then you have the same "problem" as in the case of multiple characters which you mention in your question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, `cin` is a bit finicky when it comes to `>>` and will enter a "fail state" if it tries to read a value of the wrong type.  There are actually many other failure modes as well, and so the preferred means of reading input from the console is to use some combination of `getline` and `stringstreams`.  If you're interested, Stanford's introductory C++ programming course [has an entire chapter on how to do this](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf) available online that goes over everything from the basics of `cout` and file I/O to how to properly and safely get data from the console.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you use declare the variable string,then

```
getline (cin,user_guest); //This is correct.
```

But when you use the variable char, that's another issue. Your `getline` will not be applicable. Try to use this:

```
char user_guest;
cin.get(user_request);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to retreive the string into a buffer (not a single char).

see:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Answer (score 0):

Yes std::getline, takes the input stream, and  a std::string, or char*

You're trying to pass in a single char, and that's why you're getting an error.

FWIW, you can use getline() with a std::string.

Comment: If you want to use `std::string` you have to use the [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) free function, not the `std::istream::getline()` member function. There is no overload of the member function that takes a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to replace

```
cin >> user_request;
```

with

```
cin >> user_string;
user_request= user_string[0];
```